# Integrating a map into a java application

Tags: java, open-source, artificial-intelligence, gis, path-finding

As a part of my 4th year software engineering degree I'm doing a project in which I'm giving visualization to several path finding algorithms (for multiple agents).
The first part of my project was building a re-sizable grid environment and implementing 2-3 different path finding algorithms.

The second part involves Geographical maps. I want to able to show the user a real geographical map, for example a road map, and give the algorithm the roads data as input so that the algorithms will work on this data (i believe its called a layer in a vector map) and produce a path as an input.
So eventually i will be able to show the movements of the agents on the map according to the calculated path.

The algorithms we implemented are pretty generics in the states and data they can use, so my biggest issue is figuring out how to display the map file as part of the application and where to get the input data for my algorithm.

At the beginning i thought of something like the GoogleMaps API but I'm not sure its what I'm looking for as Google maps is for web and I'm not sure that they give access to the roads layer.

So i think that what i need is some sort of an open source GIS that i can easily integrate into a java application and i will also need sample data, which is the background image ( raster map i think) and the road layer which will be used as an input for my algorithms (A* for example).

I've never worked with such systems before so it would really help me if someone could give me some directions and recommend me a good GIS library that i can use in my project (it has to be open source)

Comment: GLG Map Server Toolkit (Java supported but it is not free) http://www.genlogic.com/map_server.html. To complement your graph path-finding algorithms, you can use JUNG 2.0 Framework. This framework can be used in GUI and non-GUI mode for data processing output before you translate the data to actual map. http://jung.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Check out NASA Worldwind, its similar to Google Earth in a lot of ways, with a Java API

http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/

Comment: is it free? which types of raster& vector map files does it support?

Comment: It is free/open source.  You'll have to check out the documentation to determine which sorts of formats it supports

Answer (score 2):

To get hands on this you may visit [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and you can download some "raw" data as XML.

Comment: i found free vector maps that include road maps for the entire world. the vector maps are in a format of .shp which library can support this format?

Comment: Wikipedia points to a php lib: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile and here is something in Java http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/layer/shape/ShapeFile.html ...

Comment: ... and maybe this one too: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/GIS/openjump/org/geotools/shapefile/Shapefile.java.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to display your map as images. It requires you to do an HTTP request (With additional parameters) and it returns you an image, that you can display.

Alternatively, you can use [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/) (which is completely written in Java).

Comment: I want this to work offline by reading from raster & vector map files.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenMap](http://openmap.bbn.com/) is an open source mapping project that supports a variety of mapping formats written in Java.